# Union of list of lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, union

How is it possible to get the following (swi-)prolog predicate:

```
union(+ListOfLists, -ResultList)
```

in the form:

```
ListOfLists = [A1, A2, A3, ..., An]

ResultList = A1 ∪ A2 ∪ A3 ∪ ... ∪ An
```

Comment: Are you treating `ListOfLists` as both an input and an output? What datatype is `ResultList` intended to be?

Comment: What kind of operation is "union"? Is it associative? Is it commutative? Depending on those things the trivial solution might be to left-fold union over the list of lists, but you could do better.

Comment: in e.g. SWI Prolog, `append( [[1,2,3],[2,4,6]], X)` returns with
`X = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6]`.

Comment: @WillNess are you trying to say that the right way to do it is `append(ListOfLists, X), sort(X, Union)`? This is a good idea! I will write an answer.

Comment: @TA_intern or even without the sort. depends whether the implementation tolerates duplicates in its representation of sets.

Comment: @WillNess not sure what you mean. The append/2 you show is defined for lists, and those are just lists. You can't use that append/2 for anything else but lists.

Comment: @TA_intern I mean I could let the lists have duplicates in them. then treat e.g. `[1,2]` and `[2,1,2]` as both representing the same set. then I wouldn't need to remove the duplicates after `append`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "union" is commutative and if the identity element is the empty set, you could trivially define:

```
union(Ls, U, Op, Empty) :-
    foldl(Op, Ls, Empty, U).
```

How do you represent your union? If it is a list, then `[]` is the empty set, and if you already have a `union/3` defined (where the last argument is the union of the first two), then:

```
union(Ls, U) :-
    foldl(union, Ls, [], U).
```

But what is the computational complexity of your `union/3`?